# stop windows 7 from warning me about opening a file

Tags: windows-7, security, windows-explorer, shared-folders, security-warning

I have a linux VM sharing a folder with windows 7. I have a file with no extension. By default it opens in my fav text editors. Everytime i double click it, i get a messaging saying files from the internet may be useful but may be malicious. How do i disable the warning and allow me to open the files in peace? (There are quite a few files and this is a long term project)

Comment: Related: [How can I disable the “Open File Security Warning” when I want to run downloaded executable files?](https://superuser.com/questions/324954/how-can-i-disable-the-open-file-security-warning-when-i-want-to-run-downloaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am speculating but perhaps because the host system is serving files that obviously are not on the target Windows 7 machine, that each file is considered a download from the internet.  Thus the problem is not in the file, but rather the download zone.  Can you investigate adding the host linux machine to the trusted zone?

Comment: That did it! http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Security-zones-adding-or-removing-websites

Answer (score 2):

You can right click the file and choose the "unblock option".

Alternativly, if you have `Group Policy Editor` / Gpedit.msc, you can navigate to  `User Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `Windows Components` > `Attachment Manager`

Then change `Do not preserve zone information in file attachments` to true.

I only recommend the above one if it is really annoying you as file security like this is a very good feature of Windows.

Comment: It looks like i do not have Gpedit.msc (i wrote it in the search/run bar and got no results) and there is no unblock button in any of the tabs in `<right click file>->properties`.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the message?

Comment: Which edition of Windows 7 do you own?

Comment: solved now but i use home premium.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can also go to the file's **Properties** tab and press the **Unblock** button to permanently unblock the file. This will delete the zone information from NTFS Alternate Data Stream of the file.

Comment: there seems to be no unblock button in any of the tabs in `<right click file>->properties` and the linux filesystem isnt ntfs. Note when copying files to my drive i get no msg. However i need to leave it on the share since i am compiling on linux and editing on windows.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that your host OS is linux.

Answer (score 0):

A registry entry can also be used instead of gpedit.msc to disable creating the Zone.Identifier NTFS Alternate Data Stream for downloaded files, which can cause permission issues:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments]
"SaveZoneInformation"=dword:00000001
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/883260/information-about-the-attachment-manager-in-microsoft-windows